# load unix executable file to ascii

Tags: matlab, load, ascii

I am simply trying to load ascii files with two columns of data (spectral data).
They were saved originally as .asc.

I need to open and edit them using text editor before I can load them into Matlab to erase the headers, but some of them somehow got converted to unix executable foramt with the .asc extension.  And others are plain text docs also with the same extension. I have no idea why they got saved with the same extension and with my same manipulation as different kind formats.

When I use the load command in Matlab, the plain text docs load normally as expected but the ones saved as unix executable kinds give me this error:

> Error using load Unable to read file filename.asc: No such file or
>   directory.

How can I either resave them (still with the same extension) or otherwise load them to be read by Matlab as standard two column data matrixes?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some code? Test data?

Comment: Please read the `help`/`doc` for the `load` function. It is only for reading MAT-files, not generic text files. If they are actually MAT-files, and haven't been corrupted in some way, then just change the extension (with no code or example file/data it's impossible to say more). Otherwise, you should try something like `textscan`, `importdata`, or `dlmread`. And make sure the file in question is in your present working directory, on your `path`, or that you specify a valid path.

Comment: When I type in the comand:  >> load alummatrix.asc it works. When I type in 
>> load mudstonematrix.asc I see 
Error using load
Unable to read file mudstonematrix.asc: No such file or directory.   This is because the first file says textedit document under "kind" in my directory. The second says "unix executable."  I think this has to do with how I am right clicking and opening them in text to edit them, but my computer is assigning the kind to the file and I don't know why it's doing it this way...

Comment: They are not corrupted (I can open them in text edit) and they are not MAT files. They are true ascii files of two columns of ~2000 spectral data points. Yes, they files are in the working directory. I just tried this:  A = importdata(alummatrix.asc) and got the error, 
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.  Why isn't importdata working?

Comment: They are not corrupted (I can open them in text edit) and they are not MAT files. They are true ascii files of two columns of ~2000 spectral data points. Yes, they files are in the working directory. I just tried this:  A = importdata(alummatrix.asc) and got the error, 
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.   Then I tried M = dlmread('alummatrix.asc')  instead of importdata.  That seemed to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If these are truly plain text files, try renaming the file from xxx.asc to xxx.txt. Then, see if you are able to edit them as desired.

Comment: Well, I'm writing an m file to analyze all .asc files in my directory, so I want them all to be consistently named...